# buildroot re-downloading packages

Tags: linux, operating-system, buildroot

I am new to buildroot, I built a simple OS and it took a lot of time downloading the kernel and the packages.

The next time I built it (after doing some changes) buildroot downloaded the kernel and the packages again.

I want to save the kernel and the packages in my computer and link them to buildroot in a way that it fetches them for each build, re-downloading is a waste of time.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow! For delimit paragraphs in the post, use just `Enter` (return). Markup `---` is used for other purposes.

Answer (score 5):

From the Buildroot user manual, section [Location of downloaded packages](http://buildroot.net/downloads/manual/manual.html#_advanced_usage) (slightly modified):

> If you maintain several Buildroot trees, it might be better to have a
>   shared download location. This can be achieved by pointing the
>   `BR2_DL_DIR` environment variable to a directory. If this is set, then
>   the value of `BR2_DL_DIR` in the Buildroot configuration is overridden.
>   The following line should be added to `~/.bashrc`.
>
> `export BR2_DL_DIR=<shared download location>`
>
> The download location can also be set in the `.config` file, with the
>   `BR2_DL_DIR` option. Unlike most options in the `.config` file, this value
>   is overridden by the `BR2_DL_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: There may be a problem to use a shared download location. If we create a package which PACKAGE_SITE_METHOD = git and PACKAGE_VERSION = master, buildroot will only download the source code once and put the zipped code under dl folder. Every time user use the shared location, buildroot seems not check the code version with local downloads and keeps using the downloaded one.

Comment: @Maruku: the PACKAGE_VERSION cannot be a branch, it won't work. It has to be something that always downloads the same source, i.e. a tag or a SHA-1. The Buildroot manual was wrong about this, it has been fixed a few days ago (https://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/commit/?id=970cb26ec22e165c9b1fea27a85cfe5762096b19). Look for the nightly manual for the correct version: http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_infrastructure_for_packages_with_specific_build_systems